# ThreeJS: How to make an object the same color as background?

Tags: three.js

Ultimately, I want to make an amorphous "sphere" look as though it is behind a fog ... thus, when coming towards the screen the sphere is more bold.  One way of doing this, I thought, was to make the object AND the background the same color, then "color the object" with lighting.

However, when I make the sphere the same color as the background, lighting (of any color or type) on the sphere no longer appears.

Can someone please help?  Thanks!

```

```
class Blob extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {

}
```

}

```
componentDidMount(){
const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
const height = this.mount.clientHeight;

this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width/height, 0.8, 1000);
this.camera.position.z = 20;
this.scene.add(this.camera);

this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});
this.renderer.setClearColor('rgb(255,255,255)');
this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

this.light = new THREE.AmbientLight('white');
this.scene.add(this.light);

this.pointLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xf442b6, 1, 150);
this.pointLight.position.set(50, 50, -50);
this.pointLight.castShadow = true; 
this.scene.add(this.pointLight);

this.spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFF);
this.spotLight.position.set(-40, 110, 20);
this.spotLight.castShadow = true;
this.spotLight.shadow.mapSize = new THREE.Vector2(1024,1024);
this.spotLight.shadow.far = 120;
this.spotLight.shadow.near = 40;
this.scene.add(this.spotLight);

this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(8, 7, 20);
this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 'rgba(255,70,111,0.5)'});
this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
this.scene.add(this.sphere);

this.start();
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  this.stop();
  this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
 }

 start = () => {
  if (!this.frameId) {
    this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  }
}

stop = () => {
  cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
}

animate = () => {
 this.sphere.rotation.x += 0.01
  this.sphere.rotation.y += 0.01
 this.renderScene()
 this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
}

 renderScene = () => {
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
 }


 render(){
   return <div
     style={{ width: `${window.innerWidth}px`, height: `${window.innerHeight}px` }}
     ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}
   />
 }
```

}

```

Comment: I don't think color can be a string like that... try a hex number like `color: 0xff8800`. Opacity must be set as a separate property. You may find it easier to just use Fog that's the same color as the scene background.

Comment: **1)** [WebGLRenderer.setClearColor](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setClearColor) takes a `THREE.Color`, not a string. **2)** @DonMcCurdy `THREE.Color` does replicate [a small subset of _named_ CSS colors](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Color.js) (like "red" and "green"), which can be set using `THREE.Color.setStyle`. But you're right, it does not support strings in the `rbg(r,g,b)` format.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy  Great idea -beating myself up having not thought of that. Thank you. ....Actually, having trouble getting the Fog to show up. I think I've moved the fog near and far enough, but I'm not seeing and affect. Is there something in my code above that would prevent the fog from taking effect?

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01, that clarifies things a bit. I see the documentation a but advanced in the understanding of the domain of 3D rendering(?).